# How TCP fragment its data

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

We all know that TCP is a streaming protocol.

Unlike UDP, which guarantees that the whole client message will be delivered to server as a single datagram (we're talking about transport layer, so avoid MTU at the moment), TCP can fragment one "message" (data that was passed to the `send` function) into several smaller packets so we have to use our own delimiters as a messages' borders.

The question is -- how TCP chooses which data should be fragmented and by which size? Is there any common / standard methods that it uses?

Comment: @Robᵩ So there's no common rules or standard methods of fragmentation?

Comment: None that are observable from an application program. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Robᵩ That's more theoretical question than the practical one actually. It's interesting to know about such things

Comment: @FrozenHeart I recommend using a network traffic analyzer (Wireshark is a good one) and take a peek at TCP packets. You'll be able to see all the minute details of fragmentation, and a lot of other interesting details in the packet header as well.

Comment: "... from the application sending or receiving the data ..." - better?  @pjcognetta

Comment: @FrozenHeart - Here is some info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size and particularly the book it references : Comer, Douglas E. (2006). Internetworking with TCP/IP. Vol. 1 (5/E ed.). Upper Saddle River, NJ, USA: Prentice Hall.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not a duplicate, the accepted answer only skims over MTU and then it goes off to explain that TCP is a stream protocol. Does not even mention MSS.

Comment: @Maxim so now we have (at least) two questions that ask the same question on the site, with vastly different answers. Do you think that is better than posting your answer to the duplicate (older) one instead?

Comment: @Maxim well I guess in fact the duplicate tries to ask the age-old _"Does one `send()` correspond to one `recv()`, or what can cause differences in number of calls?"_ which makes it too broad anyway (and Nagle isn't even discussed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP uses a parameter called [Maximum Segment Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size):

> The maximum segment size (MSS) is a parameter of the options field of the TCP header that specifies the largest amount of data, specified in bytes, that a computer or communications device can receive in a single TCP segment. It does not count the TCP header or the IP header. The IP datagram containing a TCP segment may be self-contained within a single packet, or it may be reconstructed from several fragmented pieces; either way, the MSS limit applies to the total amount of data contained in the final, reconstructed TCP segment.
>
> The default TCP Maximum Segment Size is 536. Where a host wishes to set the maximum segment size to a value other than the default, **the maximum segment size is specified as a TCP option, initially in the TCP SYN packet during the TCP handshake.** The value cannot be changed after the connection is established.

If [path MTU discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) is enabled, MSS is set to that minus TCP headers size.

On Linux `TCP_MAXSEG` socket option controls the parameter:

> if this option is set before connection establishment, it  also  changes  the  MSS value  announced to the other end in the initial packet. **Values greater than the (eventual) interface MTU have no  effect.** TCP will  also  impose its minimum and maximum bounds over the value provided.

Comment: I find the explanations of network protocols such as TCP to be extremely interesting :)

Comment: Ok, so it can be fragmented into smaller packets both on the TCP layer (each packet max. to MSS) and IP layer (each packet max. to MTU), right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Yep, TCP breaks data into segments, IP layer into fragments.